# Remover objeto svg

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte codigo que cria um clone de uma imagem. Quando por exemplo ouver uns 3 clones, apagar esse ultimo. Sem aparecer.

exemplo:

```
if (id==3){
 //apagar clone/imagem
}
```

exemplo jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/twsthyds/12/

Comment: conseguiu fazer?

Comment: No jsddle funciona bem, mas em javascript sem utilisar o jquery, é utilisar tambem o remove()?

Comment: é que no browser não funciona

Comment: nao da para usar com jquery?

Comment: Não, na console diz  $ is not defined

Comment: Atualizei para fazer sem jquery, veja o fiddler novo que postei http://jsfiddle.net/rboschini/twsthyds/30/

Comment: deu certo agora?

Comment: Deu, obrigado @RBoschini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, atualizei seu [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/rboschini/twsthyds/30/), da uma olhada.

Criei um data-tag nas imagens PAI e com isso controlo quem vou excluir.
O trecho abaixo, coloquei no final do metodo `function mousedown(e)`.

```
  var type = ddData.element.getAttribute('data-type');
  var arrTmp = document.querySelectorAll('[data-type="'+type+'"]');

  if(arrTmp.length>3){
    var el = arrTmp[0];
    el.parentNode.removeChild( el );
  }
```

Como ficou o html

```
<svg width="90%" height=500px>
    <image data-type="img1" xlink:href=/favicon.png id=img1 x=0 y=0 height=20 width=20 class="img" />
    <image data-type="img2" xlink:href=/favicon1.png id=img2 x=30 y=0 height=20 width=20 class="img" />
</svg>
```

Veja se ajuda